# How to send and get data in unet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm new to unity and unet. I'm trying to make a cricket game. 
I want to share a boolean variable between two clients.

```
if(isBatting==null){


    if (random.Next (0, 2) == 1) {

        isBatting = true;
        Instantiate(batsmanPrefab, batsmanPrefab.transform.position, batsmanPrefab.transform.rotation);

    }else {

        isBatting = false;
        Instantiate(bowlerPrefab, bowlerPrefab.transform.position, bowlerPrefab.transform.rotation);

    }

}else{

    if(isBatting){

        Instantiate(bowlerPrefab, bowlerPrefab.transform.position, bowlerPrefab.transform.rotation);

    }else{

        Instantiate(batsmanPrefab, batsmanPrefab.transform.position, batsmanPrefab.transform.rotation);

    }

}
```

in the above code, when the first person joins the network, the code will randomly assign it to batting and bowling mode. Then when another joins, he will get the current state from that boolean and get its opposite mode. But i am completely beginner in unity. So i have no idea, how to send and get data from the network server.

need help...

Answer (score -1):

One of the way, by using Command and RPC special methods.

1. **Command** Function runs on server : You first send your desired data
   on server
2. Then, Use **RPC** function to send data to connected client (inform
   connected clients).

As you are newbie I will recommend you to learn UNET first.
Here, are some useful links

1. [UNet Concepts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetConcepts.html)
2. [GTGD Tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLnzlwCRjgc)
3. [Unet Actions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html)
4. [Netwrok Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html)

give sometime in learnig follow at least on tut and docs.

Comment: Broken links, no ref to the actual functionalities

Comment: It is 2019, i have answer this in 2017. Anyway i have removed the first  broken link.